# Multi monitor setup reverts to 'Mirror Displays' upon Resume after Suspend

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, suspend, 15.10

So everything runs fine upon startup. My monitors are extended, and their positions are correct.

```
Monitor 1: Built-in Display: 1366 × 768 
Monitor 2: External VGA Monitor: 1280 × 1024
```

But when I `suspend` the system and later `resume` it, the displays are mirrorred.

```
Both Monitors: 1024 × 768
```

The displays are fine when I'm entering the password, they only get messed up after the successful login.

**Hardware:**
Dell Inspiron N5110, i7 2nd gen
nVidia GT 525M

**Software:**
Ubuntu 15.10
NVIDIA binary driver - version 352.41 from nvidia-352

What is causing this issue? If there's no easy way to fix it, could I write a script to restore the monitor configuration upon resume?

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and issue :

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

And reboot.

Comment: I almost don't believe it actually worked.. Thank you.

Comment: It worked for a while. But soon the issue reappeared. Now running the command doesn't fix anything.

Comment: An update might have caused this problem, feel free to issue that command again and restart the system. Lemme know if you still  have problems.

Comment: 5 years late to the party (with a similar issue) - how is this fixing the issues? What is the problem?